# Load text files with specific format into R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has the below format. I want to load it into R as a list, but haven't figured out how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
    , , RUN1

            V1   V2 V3    V4
    MWMT  0.027 0.002  0.002 0.007
    MSP   0.029 0.004  0.002 0.012

    , , RUN2

            V1   V2 V3    V4
    MWMT  0.029 0.003  0.005 0.006
    MSP   0.031 0.004  0.006 0.017

    , , RUN3
    ... ...
```

Comment: that is structured like an array in r. is this in a csv file? or is this a .rda file?

Comment: How was this data created? It clearly was not a data.frame but was probably something that could have been converted to one. R is best for reading in nice, rectangular data. This looks like a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
 lines1 <- readLines(textConnection(", , RUN1

        V1   V2 V3    V4
MWMT  0.027 0.002  0.002 0.007
MSP   0.029 0.004  0.002 0.012

, , RUN2

        V1   V2 V3    V4
MWMT  0.029 0.003  0.005 0.006
MSP   0.031 0.004  0.006 0.017"))

indx <- grepl(",",lines1)

lst1 <- lapply(split(lines1[-which(indx)],cumsum(indx)[-which(indx)]),function(x) read.table(text=x, header=T))
names(lst1) <- gsub("[, ]","", lines1[indx])


 lst1
 #$RUN1
 #       V1    V2    V3    V4
 #MWMT 0.027 0.002 0.002 0.007
 #MSP  0.029 0.004 0.002 0.012

 #$RUN2
 #       V1    V2    V3    V4
 #MWMT 0.029 0.003 0.005 0.006
 #MSP  0.031 0.004 0.006 0.017
```

If you have already read the data in the format, for example:

```
a1 <- array(1:60, c(2,5,6))
lapply(1:dim(a1)[3], function(i) a1[,,i])
```

Comment: +1 Or [`read.mtable`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/read.mtable.R) from my ["SOfun" GitHub package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, Thanks for the link to "SOfun".  I will check `read.mtable`.  @Jian Zhang, glad to know that it worked.

Comment: @akrun, No problem. It's not a very serious package--it's just a set of random functions I've written over the past couple of years answering questions here on Stack Overflow :-)